# redirecting a url to another url but keeping it the same window

Tags: html

I am wantint to redirect a url to another url  after a few seconds, but keeping it the same window I have been using

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=http://www.google.com/" />
```

but keeps opening another window... anyway to keep it in the same window ?

Answer (score 0):

specify target ="_self" after the url

```
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content ="3;url="http://www.google.com" target="_self"/>
```